# Error reading mapoutput of other slave's map task ,what should be the actual content of etc/hosts file of ubuntu for running Hadoop cluster

Tags: networking, ubuntu, hadoop

I setup 2 nodes (virtaul machines) hadoop cluster setup. After successfully starting dfs and mapred deamons , I run hadoop demo examples, Program gets slow after this terminal display:

```
Number of Maps = 4 Samples per Map = 10000
Wrote input for Map #0
Wrote input for Map #1
Wrote input for Map #2
Wrote input for Map #3
Starting Job`enter code here`
13/06/10 21:36:43 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 4
13/06/10 21:36:43 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 4
13/06/10 21:36:43 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201306101254_0005
13/06/10 21:36:44 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/06/10 21:36:49 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 75% reduce 0%
13/06/10 21:36:50 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0%
```

So basically map tasks are being completed correctly.I checked this behaviour after looking at attempt log, particaularly attempt log of reduce task which confirm that the reduce task is unable to read mapoutput generated by the other slave**, error is like this:

```
****13/06/11 01:55:45 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://hadoop-desk.localdomain:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&taskid=attempt_201306110154_0001_m_000000_0&filter=stdout
13/06/11 01:55:45 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://hadoop-desk.localdomain:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&taskid=attempt_201306110154_0001_m_000000_0&filter=stderr
13/06/11 01:55:49 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 75% reduce 16%****
```

So the map task which generated this mapoutput is considered fail and rescheduled on different slave(slave in which reduce is running), making whole program slow. I think the reason is because of the etc/hosts of ubuntu which is:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   hadoop-desk.localdomain hadoop-desk
192.168.196.128 master
192.168.196.129 slave


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

I am getting the same error even after removing localhost,this line

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

And I removed this line

```
127.0.1.1   hadoop-desk.localdomain hadoop-desk
```

Then i got this error:

```
Number of Maps = 4 Samples per Map = 10000
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.dfs.SafeModeException: Cannot delete /user/hadoop-user/test-mini-mr. Name node is in safe mode.
The ratio of reported blocks 0.0000 has not reached the threshold 0.9990. Safe mode will be turned off automatically.
    at org.apache.hadoop.dfs.FSNamesystem.deleteInternal(FSNamesystem.java:1494)
    at org.apache.hadoop.dfs.FSNamesystem.delete(FSNamesystem.java:1466)
    at org.apache.hadoop.dfs.NameNode.delete(NameNode.java:425)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:452)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:888)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:216)
    at org.apache.hadoop.dfs.$Proxy0.delete(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:59)
    at org.apache.hadoop.dfs.$Proxy0.delete(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.dfs.DFSClient.delete(DFSClient.java:529)
    at org.apache.hadoop.dfs.DistributedFileSystem.delete(DistributedFileSystem.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.PiEstimator.launch(PiEstimator.java:188)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.PiEstimator.run(PiEstimator.java:245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.PiEstimator.main(PiEstimator.java:252)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.examples.ExampleDriver.main(ExampleDriver.java:53)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobShell.run(JobShell.java:54)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobShell.main(JobShell.java:68)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ubuntu 8 (dont know about above versions) has this entry in etc/hosts file

```
127.0.1.1   yourhostname.localdomain yourhostname
```

this entry was creating problems so comment that line, Heres my "etc/hosts" file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
#127.0.1.1  hadoop-desk.localdomain hadoop-desk
192.168.196.128 master
192.168.196.129 slave


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

after that this error will came:

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.dfs.SafeModeException: <Cannot delete /user/hadoop-user/test-mini-mr>. Name node is in safe mode.
```

To avoid this error change this dfs.safemode.threshold.pct parameter in hdfs-default.xml from 0.999f to 0.0f

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.safemode.threshold.pct</name>
  <value>0.00f</value>
  <description>
    Specifies the percentage of blocks that should satisfy 
    the minimal replication requirement defined by dfs.replication.min.
    Values less than or equal to 0 mean not to wait for any particular
    percentage of blocks before exiting safemode.
    Values greater than 1 will make safe mode permanent.
  </description>
</property>
```

Now I was still getting "error reading mapoutput" (mapoutput of different slave). I had same hostname for both master and slave, so I changed their hostname to "master" and "slave" respectively by editing their respective "etc/hostname" files. Since I already had entry for "master" and "slave" in etc/hosts file, I didnt get any error.